# How can I trim the end of a binary file?

Tags: file-io, vb6

I am using the following code to insert text into an arbitrary section of a file:

```
Dim prebuffer() As Byte
Dim postbuffer() As Byte

Dim number As Integer
number = FreeFile

Open file For Binary Access Read Write Lock Read Write As number

ReDim prebuffer(after - 2)
ReDim postbuffer(LOF(number) - before)

Get number, 1, prebuffer
Get number, before, postbuffer

Seek number, 1

Put number, , prebuffer
Put number, , value
Put number, , postbuffer

Close number
```

`after` and `before` are longs retrieved from previous calls to `Seek(number)`. When `after` equals `before`, I simply want to insert data without erasing any. But when `after` is less than `before`, I'm overwriting existing data with some of my own.

This works great when `(before - after) <= Len(value)`, as Windows knows to increase my file size to accommodate the new bytes. However, when I'm inserting less bytes than I'm removing, the file does not shrink, and leaves the existing bytes there.

For example, if my binary file is `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` and I want to insert `HELLO` with `after=5` and `before=15` I get `abcdeHELLOopqrstuvwxyzvwxyz`, with `vwxyz` being repeated. How do I shrink the file so that I only get `abcdeHELLOopqrstuvwxyz`?

---

Clarification: I know that I could delete the original file and write the entire buffer back, but I'm aiming for high performance, and wrote the insert this way because reading and writing the entire file line-by-line was too slow. Also, I would like to keep the properties of the file in tact, and don't want to destroy them every time I insert a record by making an entirely new file.

Answer (score 0):

There are no native VB functions for setting the length of the file, sadly.  One might hope to use [FileAttr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fileattr-function) to get some sort of file handle the operating system can use, but this is valid only in 16-bit code.

[VBnet](http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/fileapi/truncaterandomfile.htm) suggests doing the whole thing using the Windows API functions:

- [CreateFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea) / [CloseHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms724211) to open/close the file
- [GetFileSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfilesize) to get the size from the file handle
- [SetFilePointer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfilepointer) to seek within the file
- [SetEndOfFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setendoffile) to truncate the file

I've written some simple code based on the VBnet example:

```
Option Explicit

'' constants for CreateFile
Private Const OPEN_ALWAYS As Long = 4, GENERIC_WRITE As Long = &H40000000, GENERIC_READ As Long = &H80000000, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL As Long = &H80, INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE As Long = -1

'' constants for SetFilePointer
Private Const FILE_BEGIN As Long = 0, INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER As Long = -1

'' kernel32 functions needed
Private Declare Function CreateFile Lib "kernel32" Alias "CreateFileA" (ByVal lpFileName As String, ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, ByVal dwShareMode As Long, ByVal lpSecurityAttributes As Long, ByVal dwCreationDisposition As Long, ByVal dwFlagsAndAttributes As Long, ByVal hTemplateFile As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetFileSize Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hfile As Long, lpFileSizeHigh As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function SetFilePointer Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hfile As Long, ByVal lDistanceToMove As Long, lpDistanceToMoveHigh As Long, ByVal dwMoveMethod As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function SetEndOfFile Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hfile As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hfile As Long) As Long

Sub truncatefile(filename As String, ByVal size As Currency)
    Dim hfile As Long
    Dim dwFileSizeLow As Long
    Dim dwFileSizeHigh As Long
    Dim ret As Long

    '' open the file
    hfile = CreateFile(filename, _
        GENERIC_WRITE Or GENERIC_READ, _
        0&, ByVal 0&, _
        OPEN_ALWAYS, _
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, _
        0&)

    Debug.Assert (hfile <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) '' make sure file opened OK

    '' optional: get the current file length
    dwFileSizeLow = GetFileSize(hfile, dwFileSizeHigh)
    Debug.Assert (dwFileSizeLow >= 0 And dwFileSizeHigh = 0) '' TODO: handle 2GB and higher
    Debug.Print "Old file size: " & dwFileSizeLow

    '' split length into DWORDs (TODO: handle 2GB and higher)
    dwFileSizeLow = size
    dwFileSizeHigh = 0

    '' seek to the desired file length
    ret = SetFilePointer(hfile, dwFileSizeLow, dwFileSizeHigh, FILE_BEGIN)
    Debug.Assert ret <> INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER

    '' set this as the length of the file
    ret = SetEndOfFile(hfile)
    Debug.Assert (ret <> 0)

    '' close the file handle
    Debug.Assert CloseHandle(hfile) <> 0

End Sub
```