# Visual basic write in an opened file (printLine)

Tags: vb.net, file, file-io

So I want to do this:

```
Open file "this.txt"
Write a line to this file (replacing anything else written to this file)
[Other stuff, irrelevant to the file]
Write a line to this file (replacing anything else written to this file)
Close the file
```

I thought it would be easy, but I was wrong. I tried many ways, but they all failed. Either they wouldn't let me write in an open file, or they would open the file and immediately close it (WriteAllText).

I ended up using FileOpen(), PrintLine() and FileClose() which lets me write in an open file but PrintLine only writes a new line, it doesn't replace everything in the file. Any help? Either with the printline or the whole thing

It is crucial that the file stays open until the very last moment I want it closed, (cause I have another program checking to see when this file is not open/used).

Comment: Re-tagged as VB.NET.  If this actually *is* VBA code, it's failing because VBA doesn't have `FileOpen`, `PrintLine`, or `FileClose` methods.  It would probably be a little clearer what language you're really using if we could see the code that is currently failing.

Comment: Show the code you tried.  We can help from there.  Stay away from the old VB6 architecture.

Comment: See the [FileStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.-ctor) class. Try with `FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite`.

Comment: Based on the comments I'm reading, you need to stop thinking you can just replace a line in the middle of the file.  Doesn't really work like that.  Read all the lines of the file, change the lines you want, save all the lines back to the file.

Comment: Also, don't keep the file open.  Open it, write to it, close it.

Comment: @LarsTech But I need it to be open. Also, I don't want to replace a random line in the file. Just the one line that is in it (my example). Also, where can I see what VB version I'm on? It says Visual Basic 2015, is taht it?

Comment: Why do you need the file constantly open?  That's a pretty rare requirement.

Comment: @LarsTech As I said in the op, I am using the file as a buffer for another program that's constantly checking whether this file is used or not, and when it's released it does stuff to this file. Therefore, If I release the file prematurely, the 2nd program will go-off when I don't want to.

Comment: Like I said, read all the lines of the file into a List<string>, change the line you want, write all the lines back again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is about VB.NET, then you can use [File.Open()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.open?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_File_Open_System_String_System_IO_FileMode_System_IO_FileAccess_System_IO_FileShare_) with mode = FileMode.Truncate. This clears the file on opening. This assumes that the file exists.

You can also use SetLength() to truncate:

```
Dim f As FileStream
' FileMode.Truncate also works, but the file needs to exist from before
f = File.Open("test.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)
f.SetLength(0) ' truncate to zero size
Dim line As String = "hello2"
Dim w = New StreamWriter(f)
w.WriteLine(line)
w.Flush()
w.Close()
f.Close()
```

If this is about VB6, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334917/how-can-i-trim-the-end-of-a-binary-file). One solution there is to import and use a native Windows function that does truncation.

Comment: File.Open() does clear it up on opening, but it keeps the file open and I can't write to it, or at least I can't seem to find a way to write to it. I need to be able to keep the file open AND write to it (without appending)

Comment: The file is open until you close it. I've checked that you can write to it with Truncate. Updated the answer with some code.

Comment: I tried, `Dim f As FileStream   f=file.open(......)  dim w=new streamwriter(f)   f.writeline("222")` and it doesn't write anything to the file.

Comment: See any errors? Note that you need to call close() or `w.Flush()` until you actually see the data in the file written to disk. It buffers the output.

Comment: Thank you! With flush it does show (weird that buffer would be on by default, is there any way I can set it to off by default). While knowing its existence, I was having a hard time using StreamWriter

Comment: Yes, it has `AutoFlush`. Usually it is a good practice to buffer (avoids too many disk IO), so it is on.

Answer (score -1):

In VB.Net OpenTextFileWriter does exactly what you need ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/drives-directories-files/how-to-write-text-to-files-with-a-streamwriter)):

```
Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("c:\test.txt", False)
file.WriteLine("Here is the first string.")
file.Close()
```

Comment: Tried that already. Doesn't work. It doesn't keep the file open and despite append=False it keeps appending. If you do:

`file=My.computer.......
file.writeline("1")
file.writeline("2")`

file ends up with two lines (first line "1", and second line "2")

Comment: @user3754344 You may try to use Filestream and Seek method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.seek?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: still, this would solve the append part. It wouldn't solve that it doesn't keep the file open.